# Footer at bottom of page with dynamic content area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building an app using AngularJS and Bootstrap. The page structure is fairly vanilla in that there is a header area with nav, a content section and a footer. I'm trying to get the footer to display at the bottom of content area, with it displaying at the bottom of the browser window if the content area's height is less than the height of the browser window height.

[This method here](http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) works a treat.

However, being an Angular app the content is dynamically generated and is often longer than the browser window height. When this is the case, the footer sits at the bottom of the browser window over the top of the dynamically generated content. I need to get the footer to show after the dynamically generated content. Ideally this should be done with only CSS, but I'm open to JS solutions too.

Any pointers?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Not the actual code no (it's under NDA) but I'll see if I can replicate the issue in a fiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code with the appropriate jsfiddle:

[Footer Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/h9mHc/)

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    /* bottom = footer height */
    padding: 25px;
}
footer {
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! The html styling nailed it. Thank you!

Comment: perfect answer.